# Can I use JQuery plugins in a bookmarklet like JQuerify

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to use the tablesorter plugin in the same way as the jQuerify bookmarklet.

How should I go about doing this myself, or is it available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this at the start of your bookmarklet code:

```
var s=window.document.createElement('script'); s.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'); window.document.body.appendChild(s);
```

This basically includes the jQuery library.

Edit: Also, if this is just for personal use, you may want to keep a local copy of jQuery on your computer and point the destination of the script there. It's not really considerate to be using another server's resources without permission.

Edit2: Sorry, I misread your question. Here's modified code:

```
javascript:(function(){
var s=window.document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
window.document.body.appendChild(s);
var s2=window.document.createElement('script');
s2.setAttribute('src','http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js');
window.document.body.appendChild(s2);
$('table').tablesorter();
})();
```

I broke it up into different lines so it's easier to read. Here's a condensed version:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=window.document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');window.document.body.appendChild(s);var s2=window.document.createElement('script');s2.setAttribute('src','http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js');window.document.body.appendChild(s2);$('table').tablesorter();})();
```

Comment: I'm already using JQuerify for the JQuery library, I would like to use a plugin - tablesorter

Comment: nice, thanks sudo work. Gonna try this for jquery-ui availability in a bookmarklet